# Call different constructors from different structs based on input parameter value

Tags: c++

recently I'm working on an problem like that

```
struct A {
    A() {/* Constructor A */ }
    void method() { /* method A */ }
};

struct B {
    B() {/* Constructor B */ }
    void method() { /* method B */ }
};

struct C : public A, public B {
    C(int which) :A() {}
    C() :B() {}

    static C ConstructIt(int which) {
        if (which == 1) {
            return C(which);
        }
        else {
            return C();
        }
    }
};
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    const int a = 1, b = 0;
    C examp_A = C::ConstructIt(a);
    C examp_B = C::ConstructIt(b);
    examp_A.method(); //use method A
    examp_B.method(); //use method B
}
```

I need to create a interface to call different method struct A or B based on dynamic input parameter value, since it's determined in runtime I do not want to use template partial specialization. I try to use multiple inherit to see struct A and B as bases, and conditionally select the constructors A or B, it failed caused by multiple inheritance construct the base and derived classes automatically.

With my current knowledge of C++ I don't know how to realize it (maybe it's a stupid question), thanks for help in advance.

**EDIT:**
Thanks the solution provided by Jarod42. It seems ok for me if I can modify the struct A which is fully developed. Is there a way that I could realize the above feature without modify the existed struct A? Struct B is free to change.

Comment: I am not so sure if multiple inheritance is actually the right tool to solve your use case. I'd rather prefer single inheritance, an interface, and a factory class, to select the correct implementation.

Comment: Currently, both C's constructors do the same thing: calling default constructor of `A` and `B` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want polymorphism. There are several ways.

One common way is with interface and virtual functions:

```cpp
struct C
{
    virtual ~C() = default;
    virtual void method() = 0;  
};

struct A : C {
    A() {/* Constructor A */ }
    void method() override { /* method A */ }
};

struct B  : C {
    B() {/* Constructor B */ }
    void method() override { /* method B */ }
};

std::unique_ptr<C> ConstructC(int which) {
    switch (which) {
        case 1: return std::make_unique<A>();
        case 2: return std::make_unique<B>();
        // ...
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

And then

```cpp
int main() {
    const int a = 1, b = 0;
    auto examp_A = ConstructC(a);
    auto examp_B = ConstructC(b);
    examp_A->method(); //use method A
    examp_B->method(); //use method B
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution ! It seems ok for me if I can modify the struct A which is fully developed. Is there a way that I could realize the above feature without modify the existed struct A? Struct B is free to change.

Comment: You can still create a `wrapperA` to fallback to the above solution.

Comment: @Jarod42 - I know what you mean, but you probably should write it out for them (edit your post) how to wrap an existing class you can't change to have an interface via the wrapper.  For the OP, you will have C (interface), B (inherits from C), A (unchanged, original), and `wrapperA` which will inherit from C, and have an instance of A inside it.

Comment: Wrapper can be found in others question, such as [c-using-a-base-class-as-the-implementation-of-an-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686210/c-using-a-base-class-as-the-implementation-of-an-interface).

Comment: Thanks Jarod and Kevin! My problem solved.